# Python's html.unescape equivalent in Clojure

Tags: clojure

In Python3, we have a function like this

```
Python 3.8.5 (v3.8.5:580fbb018f, Jul 20 2020, 12:11:27) 

>>> from html import unescape

>>> unescaped = unescape("here is &#39; apostrophe")

>>> print(unescaped)

here is ' apostrophe
>>>
```

I'm having trouble finding an equivalent in Clojure. Does a base library function exist.

Comment: I wouldn't _expect_ it to exist in the Clojure standard library; it smells like something already covered by Java, JavaScript, or otherwise platform-specific libraries that Clojure provides access to, where there would be very little benefit to reimplementing the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library `apache.commons.text` can do this job:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:import
    [org.apache.commons.text StringEscapeUtils]))

(dotest
  (let [hng      "hi & goodbye"
        encoded  (StringEscapeUtils/escapeHtml4 hng)]
    (is= encoded "hi &amp; goodbye")
    (is= hng (StringEscapeUtils/unescapeHtml4 encoded))))
```

The Apache site has [the full API docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/index.html).